# Unable to figure out syntactical error in MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a short question but i can't figure out the syntactical error in this line:

`$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET userName = '$username_change' WHERE userID = '$_SESSION['userid']' ");`

I know the problem is with `$_SESSION` variable but don't what, if anything, i need to escape or alter for the statement to work.

Comment: don't use `mysql_xxx()`. These functions are considered obsolete. Switch to using either the `mysqli_xxx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your array variables within curly brackets:

> UPDATE user SET userName = '$username_change' WHERE userID =
>   '{$_SESSION['userid']}'

Also think about moving away from the **mysql_*** functions.

Comment: And move towards **mysqli** functions?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET userName = '".$username_change."' WHERE userID = ".$_SESSION['userid']);
```

Comment: While this does fix the problem, it's only by chance - simply changing to concatentation for the $username_change does absolutely NOTHING. `$x = "a$b"` is functional identical to `$x = "a" . $b`. I'd -1, but since you're not completely wrong...

Comment: @Marc B: YOu rea right...I am used to see all my variables clearly in my editor...bad habit, also he should use PDO...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE user SET userName = '$username_change' WHERE userID = "'.$_SESSION['userid']."' "
```